Obtener datos no repetidos de un array php
después de dar tantas vueltas requiero de su ayuda, lo que quiero es que solo muestre los no repetidos, ejemplo:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => BX
        )    
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => CEN
        )    
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => KGM
        )    
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => CEN
        )
)

lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => BX
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_warehouse] => 27
            [code] => KGM
        )
)

Intente con lo siguiente sin éxito ya que siempre muestra uno de los repetidos, lo que quiero es que todos los repetidos se eliminen del array:
$arraySinDuplicados = [];
foreach($arr as $elemento) {
    if (!in_array($elemento, $arraySinDuplicados)) {
        $arraySinDuplicados[] = $elemento;
    }
}


En el ejemplo que has puesto no se eliminan los repetidos, sino aquellos que aparecen más de una vez, es decir, el objeto con CEN aparece dos veces y acabas eliminandolo completamente de tu salida esperada. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo obtener un array de valores únicos. La idea es que establezcas una clave para cada objeto y te quedes con un objeto por clave. Edita tu pregunta si el objeto CEN debería salir en tu resultado esperado y respondete tú mismo si adaptas el algoritmo enlazado a tus objetos.

Tal como te indicó @RubioRic tu código remueve los duplicados, pero lo que tú quieres es que si un elemento se repite, ese elemento no esté presente, ni el original ni el duplicado.
Se me ocurre que debes agruparlos primero. Toda agrupación puede ser guardada en un diccionario de arrays. Para un diccionario necesitas una clave, en tú caso son todos los campos, por lo que perfectamente la clave puede ser el JSON del objeto, de esta manera un objeto cuyos valores sean iguales tendrá la misma clave:
$arrayAgrupados = [];
foreach($arr as $elemento) {
    $arrayAgrupados[json_encode($elemento)][] = $elemento;
}

Luego para quitar los duplicados, solo debes filtrar los elementos. Cuyo criterio será que el array interno sea de longitud 1
$SoloUnicos = array_filter($arrayAgrupados,fn($a) => count($a) ==1 );

Esto nos da un diccionario, pero tu requieres un array unidimencional, por lo que debemos convertirlo:
$resultado = array_values(array_map(fn($a) => $a[0], $SoloUnicos));


Gracias por su apoyo, me sirvió de mucho

@GutoCCayro Que buen, recuerda marcar alguna de las respuestas como aceptadas si así te lo parece. Saludos

Mi solución es básicamente la misma que ya te propusieron pero en menos pasos

Agrupar los warehouses por code
Filtrar los que aparezcan 2 o más veces

Ejemplo:
// Agrupamos por code
$grouped = array_reduce($array, function($acc, $item) {
    $acc[$item->code][] = $item;
    return $acc;
}, []);

// Eliminamos los que estén 2 o más veces
$filtered = array_reduce($grouped, function($acc, $item) {
    if (count($item) == 1) $acc[] = $item[0];
    return $acc;
}, []);

Demo

Genial estimado, muchas gracias
